# River boat problem with current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

In the case of a boat trying to reach the opposite bank in a river having a certain current speed, if the velocity of boat with respect to the river is actually less than the current speed of river, then for minimum drift to occur, why should the boat's absolute velocity(w.r.t. a ground observer) be perpendicular to the boat's velocity relative to the river?Can someone use a mathematical proof using elementary geometry,cuz geometry isn't my cup of tea!